# Using \ as a escape character is giving an unexpected output

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

[image]    string sample="How to add doublequotes";
string str = '"'+sample+'"';

This is the output I am getting - `"\"How to add doublequotes\""`
I want the output as `str= "How to add doublequotes"`
I am using vs code19

Comment: I even tried with \ and @, but getting the same output

Comment: When you say "output" what do you mean? Did you run `Console.WriteLine(str)`?

Comment: I put a debugger
In the debugger output, its showing this

Comment: Try doing str = str.Replace("\",string.empty)
You will get the same result - the string you are seeing is just in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The output that appears in your debugger is not the output you'll receive on screen.
When printing this out to [Console / API / Website], everything will work as expected.

To see what I mean, try creating a console application with the following code on Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "\"This is with doublequotes\"";
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

BTW: You can just write `string str = "\"How to add doublequotes\""` and it would still work.

Comment: I have to use this in the query string
i.e something like this-
Select * from tbl where Username=username
suppose the value of username="abc"
Now, in the query string, it goes as - Select * from tbl where username=abc
What its should go as is Select * from tbl where username="abc"
I hope you got my point!

Comment: @SiddharthKumarShukla the same applies for the query. if `string username = "abc"` then `Select * from tbl where username=\"" + username + "\""`

Comment: @Administrator **Do not encourage SQL Injection**

Answer (score -1):

If you use special characters or a newline in your text, you can use verbatim strings. They are denoted, by putting an @ before the string. Within a verbatim string, you don't need to escape special characters anymore, with one exception: the double quotes " need to be escaped using another double quotes:

```
string sample = @""How to add double quotes"";
```

When combining verbatim strings with interpolated strings, you ought to put the $ first:

```
string sample = $@"He said: ""Yes, for sure!"", but was only {p.Value} ÷ sure about it.";
```

Answer (score -1):

Error Resolved by using this-

```
string query = "select * from customer where country = '" + USERNAME + "'";
```

Thanks everyone for investing your precious time!

Comment: **Do not do this**. Please read the duplicates.